# Android - Firebase Firestore - Write the same document to different collections

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I have to write the **same** document to different collections, so I think that batched writes are not good for this. I would like to know if there is a function in firestore database, I expect written in javascript, that can copy a document I write once and paste it to different locations. These locations should be read from an array in the database.

Anyone could help me?

Thanks a lot and sorry for my low English.

Comment: Why do you think batch write is not good for this? And why would you need to write it to two collections? Could they not both reference the same record id?

Comment: I am creating a group chat app and for notifications I have to paste the same document to every member collection where they listen. Creating only one collection for every group means that every user should have a listener for every group where he is... I think not a good idea.

Comment: Oh it's a very good idea. Please see my answer and also please take a look at one of my **[tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee)** step by step, how you can **[duplicate data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KPpvNR8PqW8&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&index=11)** in order to achieve the exact thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) in Cloud Firestore are meant for this exact purpose.

> You can execute multiple write operations as a single batch that contains any combination of set(), update(), or delete() operations. A batch of writes completes atomically and can write to multiple documents.

And as a response to your question, yes, you can write the same document to different collections using this the batched writes operation.

And this how it looks like in code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference productsRef = rootRef.collection("products");
CollectionReference newProductsRef = rootRef.collection("newProductsRef");

WriteBatch writeBatch = rootRef.batch();
batch.set(productsRef.document(), yourObject);
batch.set(newProductsRef.document(), yourObject);

// This how you commit the batch
writeBatch.commit().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Using this code, you'll be able to write the same `yourObject` object to two different location in your Cloud Firestore database.

Comment: What is the right way to write the same document using batched writes?

Comment: Thank you very much. Last answer... can I write something like 500 times the same document in some millis like I'm writing it only one time?

Comment: There are some limitations.
 Please take a look at [Firestore quotas](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas). If there are too many records, I recommend you write them in small chunks to avoid writing problems.